# How to find ip and mac addresses of some popular web sites/servers

Tags: networking

I would like to know how to find IP address and/or a MAC addresses of some popular web sites or servers servers.
For example: Google, Hotmail , Yahoo, etc.

Comment: Problem is, IP of google/yahoo and the like change regularly and you can't do anything to it. Your DNS server make this transparent for you but if you try to "pin" an IP there is a chance the service will change/not respond anymore a few days/weeks later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try e.g.

```
ping google.com
```

in a terminal (a command prompt if you are on Windows) to get the resolved IP address printed. This is the easiest way I use in practice, and it is more or less universal.

Otherwise `dig` or `nslookup` are more "correct" for the task, but might not be available, and might give more info than you want.

---

The MAC address is not printed, and I cannot imagine why it would be interesting. You probably only want the IP address.

**EDIT:** Adding my comment about MAC addresses:

> You cannot see MAC addresses for hosts other than on your local network. You can only see the router's MAC address, so if you need the foreign MAC address, then I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: yea it work < but mac addresses not show ?

Comment: the  doctor ask to find ip and mac addresses
O.o

Comment: @Ali: You _cannot_ see MAC addresses for hosts other than on your local network. You can only see the router's MAC address, so if you need the foreign MAC address, then I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Only Ethernet and WiFi endpoints have MAC addresses. A website may not have any Ethernet or WiFi endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Try an online `nslookup` service like http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php.

For example, enter "maps.google.com" in the "Domain:" box and hit return.

You can only see the MAC address of machines on your local (sub)network, so you're out of luck there (although I *can* think of some reasons that that would be interesting :) ).

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP use `nslookup` on windows or `dig` on Linux

You cannot query the MAC address as this is only known to the next switch/router in the companies infrastructure. 
Also the MAC address is specific to one single network interface whereas from the network-topology side of view behind one IP there can be hundrets of servers due to NAT/Load Balancing.